# accessing properties form a uiviewcontroler instance in objective c.

Tags: objective-c, properties, ios5, xcode4.2

im new to programming and stared on objective c. i would like to declare a property in one file and acces it form an other, however for some reason it does not work. I'm probably doing something very silly don't blame me.

i have the folling first header :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "second.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    NSString* theText;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *theText;



@end
```

here i the .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize theText,textField;

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self setTheText:textField.text];

}

@end
```

now i would like to use the theText property in an other file to both use it and change it. so i thought this would work but it don't:

the second .m file:

```
#import "second.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation second
@synthesize secLabel;

-(void)nameLabel{

    secLabel.text = [ViewController theText];
}

@end
```

the compiler says no known class method for selector. I tried a lot but nothing worked, does somebody know how to make this work?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

theText is an instance level property, but you are trying to access it on the ViewController class. Instead, you need to access it on some instance of ViewController. In other words, you need:

```
ViewController *viewController = ... some code to get a ViewController pointer ...
secLabel.text = [viewController theText];
```

Your "second" view controller somehow needs to get an instance of ViewController. How you actually get that depends on your app and I can't say without knowing more about your code.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

This will show you how to correctly make a singleton class.

It may not be the cleanest way of doing it but its on the correct path for storing data.

Comment: Thank you!
i understand the tutorual, however i do not understand where/how to call:
    MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
can you explain that?

Comment: Its what you have to do before you do any commands to access the singleton class.

Comment: so E.G. if you are changing a number after a button is pressed you would write it like this MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager]; sharedManager.number += 1; Get it?